# Issue with databinding to class?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone

I'm having an issue with databinding a textblock to a custom prop inside another class, what am I doing wrong?

```
mainpage:

  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeLanguage();

    }

    private void InitializeLanguage()
    {
        LanguageHelper lh = new LanguageHelper();

        // this.TitlePanel.DataContext = lh;
        txtTitle.DataContext = lh;
    }
}
```

databinding:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitle" 
                   Text="{Binding homepage_subheading}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" 
                   Foreground="White"
                   Margin="12,0"/>
```

LanguageHelper class:

```
public class LanguageHelper
{
    public String homepage_subheading;

    public void changeLanguage()
    {
        if (true)
        {
            //english
            homepage_subheading = "This is the top / sub Heading";
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Was changing your fields to property solved your problem? Or is it still not working?

Comment: ya sorry could only accept answer after few minutes, thanx for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a property but a public field, and the databinding engine only works on properties.

So you need to change your class:

```
public String homepage_subheading { get; set; }
```

If you want to also notify the UI with your changes of your properties your `LanguageHelper` should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and fire the `PropertyChange` event when you modify your properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare some dependency property or use `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I would like to use a dependency property:

```
public class LanguageHelper : DependencyObject {
  public static DependencyProperty Hompage_subheadingProperty =  
  DependencyProperty.Register("Homepage_subheading", typeof(string), typeof(LanguageHelper));
  public String Homepage_subheading {
     get { return (string) GetValue(Homepage_subheadingProperty);}
     set { SetValue(Homepage_subheadingProperty, value);}
  }
}
```

Note about the naming convention in `C#`, all properties should have first letter capitalized.